# does geometric realization factor through an endofunctor?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff, model-categories

Does the functor of geometric realization of a simplicial set as a topological space,
factor through an endofunctor of the category of simplicial topological spaces which does something non-trivial (in an informal sense)?

Is there a known construction showing something like this, possibly via an endofunctor of some other category? More generally, is geometric realisation known to be associated with some endofunctor ?

The motivation for the question is that it is claimed there is such a [factorisation](https://mishap.sdf.org/SkorokhodGeometricRealisation.pdf) through an endofunctor
of a category similar but distinct from the category of simplicial topological spaces,
and I'd like to know if it is related to something.

Comment: You can factor the usual geometric realization functor through the category of simplicial spaces, by considering the constant simplicial space of the geometric realization. Therefore it factors through an endofunctor of the category of simplicial spaces: the identity endofunctor. This is probably not what you have in mind, but you should narrow your question to exclude such trivial answers.

Comment: I do not know how to narrow it in a precise sense. Informally, it is a request for references to a non-trivial endofunctor associated with geometric realisation in some sense.

Comment: You can just consider geometric realisation of simplicial spaces as an endofunctor of simplicial spaces: It takes a simplicial space to the constant simplicial space given by the geometric realisation. Is this what you had in mind?